# Set example of array with ids in Swagger Property (OAS3)

Tags: php, swagger, openapi, swagger-php

I'm trying to specify the following requestBody in swagger (OAS3):

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "interest_ids": [
     1,2
  ]
}
```

I currently have specified the requestBody as follows:

```
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *          required=true,
 *          @OA\JsonContent(
 *              required={"email"},
 *              @OA\Property(property="first_name", type="string", format="string", example="John"),
 *              @OA\Property(property="last_name", type="string", format="string", example="Doe"),
 *              @OA\Property(property="email", type="string", format="email", example="user@example.com"),
 *              @OA\Property(property="interest_ids", type="array", @OA\Items(
 *                      type="integer",
 *                      example=3
 *                  ),
 *              ),
 *          ),
 *     ),
```

This gives me a correct requestBody, however this obviously gives me only one key with value `3` as example value for the `interest_ids` array. How can I specify multiple ids without setting the type to string? I have tried multiple solutions, for example setting examples as `example={1,2}`, this unfortunately gives me another array within the `interest_ids` array:

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "interest_ids": [
    [
      1,
      2
    ]
  ]
}
```

I've also tried setting `collectionFormat` on the property type to different values, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried moving the example from `@OA\Items` up into the property?

Right now the example is the example of a single value of the array.

I suppose what you want is an example of `interest_ids` itself.

```
 *       @OA\Property(property="interest_ids", type="array",
 *         example={3, 4},
 *         @OA\Items(
 *           type="integer"
 *         )
 *       )
```

Comment: Wow, this was indeed the solution, can't believe I didn't try that earlier. Thank you very much!